# am trying to reduce the score when a condition satisfies

Tags: python, pandas, loops, dataframe

Am trying to reduce a score when the condition satisifies. But failing to do so.

```
data = ['A','B']
Score = 10
words = [ 'C', 'D']

for i in data:
     if i in words:
          do nothing
     else:
         reduce score by 2
```

Here, when both A and B are not there in words, I want my score to reduce only once, but not twice.

```
Expected output : 8
```

code :

```
index = []
for i in data:
     if i in words:
          do nothing
     else:
         index.append(something)

if len(index) > 1:
       reduce score by 2
```

This is what I have written, but is there a way to make this even less complicated ??

Comment: kindly share the input dataframe ( a couple of rows) and ur expected output as well. kindly share data, not pics.

Comment: you could try using the `any()` method

Comment: @SowjanyaRBhat can you elaborate ?

Comment: @sammywemmy I guess I have given my data and expected result as well

Comment: my bad. u had pandas as a tag, as such i expected a dataframe.

Comment: @sammywemmy sorry for it. I had to tag it, as am using it for my dataframe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
data = ['A','B']
score = 10
words = [ 'C', 'D']

data_not_found_list = [False for dt in data if dt not in words]

if not any(data_not_found_list):
    score -= 2

print(score)
```

Output :
`8`

I have made use of the any() method here . You can read how it works to get an idea - https://realpython.com/any-python/